# De-Obfuscate PHP Code of mine

Tags: php, deobfuscation

I've obfuscated one of my php code at http://www.phpencode.org/ but forgot to take backup of that file and now I need to modify that file. Please help me to ed-obfuscate. It also has my licensing check so I need to make it work as I've modified my licensing modules.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/1bxBpk0Q

[NOTE] This code only runs if the file is not modified use the raw version of paste.

Comment: Replace `eval` with `print` yourself. Rinse, repeat. (Or look through all the similar questions, there are automated tools for that..)

Comment: In the process of solving this problem you will discover why obfuscation is pretty much worthless.

Comment: @mario I'm trying, but the problem is I can't edit the file as changing the characters stops everything, this obfuscation works in this way.

Comment: Oh yes.. I got it.. Its too easy man... Thanks!! You are right @cdhowie, "obfuscation is pretty much worthless"

Answer (score 3):

Obfuscating PHP code. Certainly is worthless.

Here is a decrypter: http://decode-phpencode.eu.pn/

And here is the source code:

```
<?php

/* This program is released under the MIT license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT */

# stripslashes may be needed on servers that uses magicquotes
$file = stripslashes($_POST['file']);
# This decodes the first eval string
$first_eval_string = base64_decode(preg_replace("/.*eval\(base64_decode\(\"([^\"]+)\".*/", "$1", $file));
# That contains an array with byte positions inside the encryted string
$array = preg_split("/,/", preg_replace("/.*array\(([\d,]+).*/", "$1", $first_eval_string));
# The area where the code begins we get it just by summing the numbers in the array
$begin = array_sum($array);
# We get the content from that area and decrypted. That's it.
echo "<?php\n";
echo gzinflate(
    base64_decode(
        trim(
            substr($file,$begin)
        )
    )
);
```

And the first result of googling "phpencode.org decoder" is this other decoder: http://lombokcyber.com/detools/welcome/cdecodezeura1